# How can I specify trait bounds with OR logic

Tags: rust

I am looking to implement 2D matrix functionality in Rust in a generic fashion where the elements of the matrix would be numerics (either i32, i64, u32, u64, f32, f64). The generic type would look something like shown below:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Mat<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
    shape: (usize, usize),
}

impl<T> Mat<T> where T: i32 OR i64 OR u32 OR u64 OR f32 OR f64{
    pub fn new(){
        ...
    }
}
```

I know that you can **AND** trait bounds with the **+** symbol in the form of "**where T: bound1 + bound2**". Is there a way to cleanly **OR** trait bounds together?

Comment: Note: For this specific case, you probably just want to use [the `num` crate's `num::Num` trait](https://docs.rs/num/latest/num/trait.Num.html) (or the same thing from `num_traits` to limit to just the traits, not the rest of `num`) to just allow any numeric type if you want to support arbitrary numeric types. Or use the specific `std::ops` traits to specify which operations must be supported without specifically requiring something that `num` defines the traits for (or for non-builtins, something that implements the traits from `num`).

Comment: I think the question could be better phrased. It is not about trait bounds. `i32` and `i64` a types (not traits) and could also not be combined with `+` to a trait bound. There is a way to implement a trait for a fixed list of types, but this is also not what you want.

I would like to encourage you to look at the operations you need and just express them as types. E.g. the traits in `std::ops` or the `num_traits` crate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am now checking out num_traits. I am trying to challenge myself to stay with the standard library in order to figure out the quirks of rust but a programmer gotta do what a programmer gotta do sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

No, but this isn't usually what you want anyway.  You can do this by declaring a tag trait, like:

```
pub trait NumberTrait {}

impl NumberTrait for i32 {}
impl NumberTrait for i64 {}
// and so on...

impl<T> Mat<T> where T: NumberTrait { ... }
```

However, usually what you're *actually* trying to accomplish is enforcing that `T` supports some set of operations like addition and multiplication.  If so, just bound on those operations:

```
use std::ops::*;

impl<T> Mat<T> where T: Add<T, Output=T> + Mul<T, Output=T> { ... }
```

This will cover all of the primitive numeric types, but will *also* cover other types for which those operations are defined, such as third-party "decimal" or "big number" (e.g. 128/256/512-bit integers) types.

Comment: I see. Yes, Using the std::ops as bounds is my solution. Now though, I am running into an issue where I am trying to specify a zero and One on T since it is numeric but the compiler is unhappy with `let sum: T = 0` saying "expected parameter T found Integer". Any ideas how to get around that with a Trait bound. I don't think std::ops will save me this time. PS: I am new to Rust Generic programming. It is powerful (easier than the C++ version) but it does bite a lot.

Comment: I am thinking to implement a trait for T with member functions zero() and one() which will yield the correct 0 and 1 based on the realized T at the call point. But I feel it's another minefield and feels inelegant.

Comment: @Claver For 0 you can just additionally bound on `T: Default`, since the `Default` implementations on numeric types return 0. For 1 you will likely need a trait, yes. Note that traits can have `const` attributes, so you could do e.g. `trait One { const ONE: Self; }` and then `impl One for i8 { const ONE: i8 = 1; }` etc. You could also put the implementation in a macro. There's also [`One`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/identities/trait.One.html) from `num_traits` but, unfortunately, it's not a `const` attribute.